# Patterns.ask and Await.result thread safety in akka java

Tags: java, multithreading, akka

I have a RMI controller which receives requests through the network. This controller delegates responsibility on an akka actor which later on the time gets in touch with a pool of workers for resolving an algebraic operation.

Is enough the below piece of code to ensure that my akka master actor (masterActor) will receive and respond properly all the request from each thread that RMI creates for each request to my controller? I mean, are Patterns.ask and Await.result thread safe? Have they a way to access with mutual exclusion to masterActor reference? Or I need to create a critical section in my controller?

```
Class MyController extends ... {

/* ... */
ActorRef masterActor;
/* ... */

public <O extends AlgebraOp<R>, R extends Equation & Resolved> R resolve(
        Equation AlgebraOp, Context context){

    EquationAndContext message = new EquationAndContext(AlgebraOp, context);

    Future<R> future = (Future<R>) Patterns.ask(masterActor, message, timeout);
    R operationResolved = null;
    boolean timeoutExpired = false;

    while(!timeoutExpired) {
        try {
            operationResolved = (R) Await.result(future, timeout.duration()); 
            timeoutExpired = true;
        } catch (Exception timeExpired) {
            /* Re-build the future for next try */
            future = (Future<R>) Patterns.ask(masterActor, message, timeout);
        }
    }

    return operationResolved;
   }

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Yes they are.**

If `resolve` is concurrently called, you will see no problem regarding `Patterns.ask` and `Await.result`.

Comment: Then the master will forward the messages properly and will retrieve the suitable response?

Comment: If that is what the master does when it receives a ``EquationAndContext`` message, then yes

Comment: the master only forwards that operation to a worker which finally does  some calculations and returns the result to resolve method using  getSender().

Comment: Since there is a synthetic temporary actor reference behind each Future created by ask, if the answer is going to the proper sender from the worker (i.e. any intermediate actors use "forward" to keep the orignal sender intact) then you get the proper "answer."